# WaitForNextEvent in powershell

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, wmi, powershell-3.0

i am new to powershell having not much idea about, i tried writing script to kill unnecessary processes but receiving below exception

Exception calling "WaitForNextEvent" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid class "

can anyone help ??

Comment: As per answer from **postanote**, pleas provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Show your code. 
Otherwise we cannot help, specifically with your issue.

You say you are new, and that is fine, but you should really spend time getting up to speed on PowerShell via [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/getting-started-with-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6), [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), [MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com/training-topics/powershell#!lang=1033), [MSChannel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=powershell&lang-en=true), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell), [eBooks](https://leanpub.com/u/devopscollective), use the help files.

```
# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

# Get a list of all functions
Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions'

# Get a list of all commandlets
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available cmdlets'

# Get a list of all functions for the specified name
Get-Command -Name '*process*' -CommandType Function | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available named functions'

# Get a list of all commandlets for the specified name
Get-Command -Name '*process*'  -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available named cmdlet'

# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-Process).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Online


# Get parameter that accepts pipeline input
Get-Help Get-Process -Parameter * | 
Where-Object {$_.pipelineInput -match 'true'} | 
Select * 


# List of all parameters that a given cmdlet supports along with a short description:
Get-Help dir -para * | 
Format-Table Name, { $_.Description[0].Text } -wrap
```

This would have given you what you needed to do what you are after and eliminate unnecessary confusion / frustration, that you will encounter.

As for your use case, this is really basic PowerShell stuff.

```
# Get all Process
Get-Process

# Get a named process
Get-Process -Name Notepad

# Get multiple processes
'iexplore', 'notepad', 'aesm_service' | ForEach{ Get-Process -Name $_}

# Ending named or multiple processes
Stop-Process -Name Notepad
'iexplore', 'notepad', 'aesm_service' | ForEach{ Stop-Process -Name $_ -Force}
```